# Laptop won't "hibernate" then "thaw"

Tags: suspend-resume

Can anyone help me with a suspend-resume problem?

I have two identical ThinkPad laptops (7764CTO).  One works fine. The other will not "hibernate" (suspend-to-disk) and "thaw" (restart after suspend-to-disk).  The alternative "sleep" (suspend-to-ram) and "resume" (restart after suspend-to-ram) works fine.

I don't find any log contents (that make sense to me) to tell me:

- Did suspend-to-disk reach **successful** completion? If not, what went wrong?
- Did start-up **successfully** detect the need to restart-from-hibernate? If successful suspend, why did detection fail?
- Did restart-from-hibernate fail its processing? What was going on at the time of failure?

I found postings about suspect modules and problem devices (where suspend-to-XXX matters) and made some progress, but the fact that one laptop works while one fails is driving me crazy.

Completely stumped.

Comment: Same partition layout on both?

Answer (score 2):

How big is your SWAP? For default hybernation you need at least 2xRAM of swapspace. You can configure your kernel to use a file-swap instead, but this is not standard and a bit harder to install

Comment: I have a netbook with 2 GiB ram and 600 MiB swap. I hibernate regularly with absolutely no problem. I installed stock Ubuntu Netbook.

Comment: I didn't say it was impossible, but even the swapFaq (and the help while installing says: ***Ubuntu Desktop uses Swap to Hibernate (PC off, no power needed, program states saved). If Hibernation is important to you, have more swap space then ram + swap overflow.*** (via; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq )