# 14.04.1: Hibernation Won't Work

Tags: 14.04, hibernate, tuxonice

(I have a similar problem to [Laptop won't "hibernate" then "thaw"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27425/laptop-wont-hibernate-then-thaw))

Hi

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro S500, with windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot. 
I would like Ubuntu 14.04 to hibernate, and I can't get it to work.

It appears to hibernate to disk and shut down (power off). I come to turn my computer back on, and sometimes Ubuntu starts up as if there was no hibernation, other times it appears to resume hibernate from disk, and then freeze up, requiring a ALT+SYSRQ+B. Sudo pm-hibernate doesn't work (its essentially a long shutdown command)

My file to add the option to hibernate in the shutdown/power menu exists in
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
and the contents are this

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
[Re-enable hibernate by default for login1]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
[Re-enable hibernate for multiple users by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

Output of free (took out buffers line):

```
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3774016    1758200    2015816     346256      69016     902324
Swap:      4194300          0    4194300
```

resume=/dev/sda5 (my root partition) is added to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT (in grub)

Any idea why it isn't working? Is my computer not compatible? Swap shouldn't be the issue. Let me know if you want any logs, photos, etc

I would rather not have to use TuxOnIce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your machine doesnt support hibernation. Please test your machine by

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then `sudo pm-hibernate`

Your machine should hibernate. Start your machine up after hibernation and observe if it misbehaves or if it returns to the point where you were, and if it returns the windows you had open before hibernation. If it doesn't do so, then I advise you don't keep on trying, as your hardware would have shown it doesn't support hibernation. However, if it works just fine after **sudo pm-hibernate**, then go to this file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

..and check if the following lines exist:

```
[Re-enable hibernation]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Edit them in if they are not there. After this, restart your machine, and then hibernate. 
Hibernation is bound to work after this.

Comment: Running `sudo pm-hibernate` does nothing. Not going to bother hibernation, I never use it anyway :)

Comment: Are you talking about the case where the **hardware** doesn't support hibernation or the **software** (Ubuntu) doesn't support hibernation **of this hardware**? If the latter - please be exact, because this is misleading.